# How do I get my terminal environment to match the vscode selected environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, conda, python-venv

I'm trying to switch environments from my "venv-02: conda" to my "venv: venv" environment. I have selected the venv environment in my vsocde by clicking here and also in the select environment prompt from pressing control shift 5.

However my terminal environment doesn't change out of venc-02. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: AFAIU, these are virtual environments. You can activate them by running the command:
`source <your venv>/bin/activate`

Comment: @vagitus This doesnt work for me sorry. I get this error: >source venv-01/bin/activate 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to switch venv in the terminal:

```
conda active venv-01
```

[image]

You can also use shortcuts **"ctrl+shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the venv then **reload the vscode**. When you try to run the file, it will automatically help you activate the conda environment.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't seem to work, I'm guessing because it's not a conda environment?

Comment: @MichaelAmosm If so, I'm not sure where your problem is. Could you please read the selection interpreter in the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters) and tell me where the problem occurred?